# javascript worked on local server but not in live server

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i am working on wordpress site right now...
i load some js in local and in live....js load perfectly in both server but don't know why my js is not working in live server....
this is the list of js that i loaded in both server...

```
function underskeleton_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('underskeleton-datepicker',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js',array(),'1.0.4',true);
wp_enqueue_script('underskeleton-scripts',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/theme.min.js',array(),'1.0.0',true);
wp_enqueue_script('underskeleton-owl-carousel',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/common_scripts.min.js',array(),'1.0.1',true);
wp_enqueue_script('underskeleton-owl-carousel-min',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/common.js',array(),'1.0.3',true);
wp_enqueue_script('underskeleton-function',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/functions.js',array(),'1.0.2',true);
wp_enqueue_script('underskeleton-datepicker',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js',array(),'1.0.5',true);

if(is_singular()&&comments_open()&&get_option('thread_comments')) {
wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','underskeleton_scripts');
```

all js files loaded perfectly but didnt work....

this is link of that page.....
http://isyncevolution.com/project/wp/dentist/detail-page/

in this page there is calender but i can't see that as js isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your browser console you see that 3 of your scripts are looking for jQuery, but this is not loaded.

When using wp_enqueue_script you can pass an array of registered script handles as 3rd parameter, so in your case:

```
wp_enqueue_script('underskeleton-datepicker',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js',array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.4',true);
```

Here you can find a list of all the handlers available in WP: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 0):

You have not added jquery. enqueue jquery before datepicker.js or paste this line before you are enqueuing  datepicker.js.

```
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.11.3');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

You have not defined datepicker with your "calender" div that's why it is not showing there. add this line into your code and date picker will be visible. for checking purpose you can also add this in you dev console.

`jQuery( "#calendar" ).datepicker();`

Comment: gave  504-gateway time out error....  the problem in here is js is not working....not just date picker but all js loaded but not working.....

Comment: i didnt get any error now before there was an error that jquery is not defined. show some code ie: where you added datepicker in this page.

Comment: yes but as "Alessandro Senese" suggest i added 3rd parameter "array('jquery')" ..so that's why..

Comment: okay. can you please show some html and js code where you defined datepicker?